# dropdown onchange event is not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I want to fill the Dropdown onchange of another Dropdown like on Country change then State dorpdown should be fill and on change of state City.
I am trying to doing this by Ajax but it is not responding.
Code which i have written that is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load_options('','country');
    });

    function load_options(id,index){
        $("#loading").show();

        if(index=="state"){
            $("#city").html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
            complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#"+index).html(data);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<label>Select Country</label>
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="load_options(this.value,'state');">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
</select>

<label>Select State</label>
<select name="state" id="state" onChange="load_options(this.value,'city');">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
</select>

<label>Select city</label>
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

#### Ajax.php:

```
<?php
    class AJAX {
        private $database = NULL;
        private $_query = NULL;
        private $_fields = array();
        public  $_index = NULL;
        const DB_HOST = "localhost";
        const DB_USER = "root";
        const DB_PASSWORD = "12345";
        const DB_NAME = "AnandDb";

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db_connect();                 // Initiate Database connection
            $this->process_data();
        }
        /*
         *  Connect to database
        */

        private function db_connect(){
            $this->database = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOST,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);

            if($this->database){
                $db =  mysql_select_db(self::DB_NAME,$this->database);
                echo "Db connect.";
            } else {
                echo mysql_error();die;
                echo "Db Not connected.";
            }
        }

        private function process_data(){
            $this->_index = ($_REQUEST['index'])?$_REQUEST['index']:NULL;
            $id = ($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:NULL;
            switch($this->_index){
                case 'country':
                $this->_query = "SELECT country_id,country_name FROM tbl_country";
                $this->_fields = array('id','country_name');
                break;

                case 'state':
                $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_state WHERE country_id=$id";
                $this->_fields = array('id','state_name');
                break;

                case 'city':
                $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_city WHERE state_id=$id";
                $this->_fields = array('id','city_name');
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
            $this->show_result();
        }

        public function show_result(){
            echo '<option value="">Select '.$this->_index.'</option>';
            $query = mysql_query($this->_query);
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $entity_id = $result[$this->_fields[0]];
                $enity_name = $result[$this->_fields[1]];
                echo "<option value=".$entity_id.">".$enity_name."</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    $obj = new AJAX;
 ?>
```

Comment: problem is in Javascript or Not getting ajax response??

Comment: yes can you help me to solve the problem that what error into the javascript code.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: When i am selecting country from dropdown it is not responding. but when i run `Ajax.php` in browser it is working fine. So my error in Javascript code and Javascript code is not sending the index and id value on the `ajax.php` page.

Comment: can you please alert and check the value of id and index in javascript and check whether value is correct or not. Commentyour ajax code and check it.

Comment: I agree with Vinoth. Another thing to try is use a tool like firebug in firefox to see what/if the browser is requesting. It will also show you what the server responds with (ok, not found, server error, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is not any other error. But dont use id and index in javascript function. Rename those variables and try. Try to alert those two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" 
onChange="load_options(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'state');">
```